# Python: generator fail

Tags: python, generator

```
def sp():
    i = 0
    while True:
        for j in range(i):
            yield(j)
        i+=1
```

This generator is supposed to `yield` all the integers in the `range` of `(0, i)`, but it keeps returning `0` with every call of `next()`. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't just do `sp().next()`. You need to instantiate (?) the generator: `s=sp(); s.next(); s.next();`...

Comment: But if you just want 0, 1, 2, ... then you don't want that `range(i)` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't. This is the output:

```
>>> s=sp()
>>> s
<generator object sp at 0x102d1c690>
>>> s.next()
0
>>> s.next()
0
>>> s.next()
1
>>> s.next()
0
>>> s.next()
1
>>> s.next()
2
>>> s.next()
0
>>> s.next()
1
>>> s.next()
2
>>> s.next()
3
>>> s.next()
0
>>> s.next()
1
>>> s.next()
2
>>> s.next()
3
>>> s.next()
4
```

which is exactly what you would expect. Each time, you start from 0 and go to whatever `i` is, then start back from 0 again up to the next value of `i`.